# C# Security Claims Value Outdated

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

when I'm using `ClaimTypes.Role` from `System.Security.Claims;` all of the URIs from ClaimTypes are missing.
For example `ClaimTypes.Role = http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role or ClaimTypes.Actor =  http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/actor`

The URIs give the error

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name
>   changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Does anybody know where the description has moved and if it is possible to update the `ClaimTypes` to point to the correct locations?

Looking on Microsoft's website https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimtypes.role(v=vs.110).aspx They also give the URI http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not worry about the text, best practice is to use `ClaimTypes.Role`.  The string can change to reflect the date but the Object will not so you do not have to worry about code refactor.